How do I utilize the fivetran/zendesk models from its dbt_package?
I am new to dbt packages and I am stuck trying to get the models from the dbt package 'fivetran/zendesk' to materialize.
https://hub.getdbt.com/fivetran/zendesk/latest/
As per the documentation, I added the package to my packages.yml file:
packages:
  - package: dbt-labs/dbt_utils
    version: [">=1.1.0", "<1.3.0"]
  - package: tnightengale/dbt_meta_testing
    version: 0.3.6
  - package: dbt-labs/codegen
    version: 0.12.1
**  - package: fivetran/zendesk
    version: [">=0.16.0", "<0.17.0"]**

I ran dbt deps, output here:
17:57:46  Running with dbt=1.8.3
17:57:48  Updating lock file in file path: /Users/mwufsus/Repos/dbt/package-lock.yml
17:57:48  Installing dbt-labs/dbt_utils
17:57:48  Installed from version 1.2.0
17:57:48  Up to date!
17:57:48  Installing tnightengale/dbt_meta_testing
17:57:48  Installed from version 0.3.6
17:57:48  Up to date!
17:57:48  Installing dbt-labs/codegen
17:57:48  Installed from version 0.12.1
17:57:48  Up to date!
17:57:48  Installing fivetran/zendesk
17:57:49  Installed from version 0.16.0
17:57:49  Up to date!
17:57:49  Installing fivetran/zendesk_source
17:57:49  Installed from version 0.11.2
17:57:49  Up to date!
17:57:49  Installing calogica/dbt_date
17:57:49  Installed from version 0.10.1
17:57:49  Up to date!
17:57:49  Installing fivetran/fivetran_utils
17:57:50  Installed from version 0.4.10
17:57:50  Up to date!
17:57:50  Installing dbt-labs/spark_utils
17:57:50  Installed from version 0.3.0
17:57:50  Up to date!

But when I run dbt run I do not see the models from the package materializing in my Snowflake destination, there is no error associated, it is only running the other models that I have setup myself, which are not part of packages.
To the best of my knowledge, I have added the required vars to my dbt_project.yml as per the dbt package docs:
# Project name
name: 'fake_company_analytics'
version: '1.0.0'
config-version: 2

require-dbt-version: [">=1.3.0", "<2.0.0"]

# Configuring your profile: https://docs.getdbt.com/dbt-cli/configure-your-profile
profile: 'fake_company_analytics'

# These configurations specify where dbt should look for different types of files.
# The `model-paths` config, for example, states that models in this project can be
# found in the "models/" directory. You probably won't need to change these!
model-paths: ["models"]
analysis-paths: ["analysis"]
test-paths: ["tests"]
seed-paths: ["seeds"]
macro-paths: ["macros"]
snapshot-paths: ["snapshots"]
docs-paths: ["docs"]

target-path: "target"  # directory which will store compiled SQL files
clean-targets:         # directories to be removed by `dbt clean`
  - "target"
  - "dbt_modules"
  - "dbt_packages"

# Append query comments rather than prepending them, because some databases like Snowflake remove leading comments.
query-comment:
  append: true
    
vars:
  deployment_target_names: ['production', 'prod']
  zendesk_database: fivetran
  zendesk_schema: zendesk

# Configuring models: https://docs.getdbt.com/docs/configuring-models
# These settings can be overridden in the individual model files using the `{{ config(...) }}` macro.
models:
  +materialized: ephemeral
  +schema: miscellaneous
  +bind: false  # Materialize all views as late-binding.
  +persist_docs:
    relation: true
    columns: true
  fake_company_analytics:
    marts:
      +materialized: table
      core:
        +schema: core
        intermediate:
          +schema: core_intermediate
      netsuite:
        +schema: netsuite
    sources: 
      +materialized: view
      +schema: sources
      salesforce:
        +tags: "salesforce"
        
    utils:
      +materialized: table
      +schema: utils

seeds:
  +schema: seeds
  +quote_columns: false

# unused config
# snapshots:
  # The generate_schema_name() macro doesn't apply to `target_schema`, so manually apply the same logic.
  # +target_schema: "{{ 'snapshots' if var('is_deployment', target.name in ['production', 'prod']) else target.schema ~ '_snapshots' }}"



If I run dbt test it runs tests for the fivetran/zendesk package I have installed, but I am unsure if there are unit test or actual tests against my zendesk database.
To my understanding, these dbt packages should be as simple as installing the package and executing dbt run.
I'd rather not try to reinvent the wheel and reference the dbt package from a new model where I'm just doing a SELECT * FROM {{ ref(... - that just seems silly to me.
I have tried changing package versions, uninstalling/installing the fivetran/zendesk package and modifying my config to target different destination schemas.
As someone pointed out below, I initially did not have the zendesk_schema specified in the config I posted.
Now when I execute dbt run, I can see that it is running an on-run-start hook for zendesk, but still nothing is materializing.


Are you sure you have added zendesk_schema to your dbt_profile.yml?
vars:
    zendesk_database: fivetran
    zendesk_schema: your_schema_name 


Hey, thank you for calling that out - I just updated my config in my original question to have the schema specified.

Great! I see you have ephemeral materializations for many models. Is there specific reason for that? If you remove it would it still materialize nothing in your target database?
